# Custom authz and authn service for complex use case?

Tags: authentication, service, authorization

I have case where I have several services.

User creates some resource & gets the permission as an owner.
Event is created & the resource is created in several other services as needed for the context.

How would i tackle such a problem, if i had an external user identity platform such as Auth0?
Would i need to create internal user to keep his permissions?

User should be able to share the permissions with other users and groups. Groups are groups of users.

How would i then list the users if i had external identity platform?

Now, do people create custom services that include their own custom - fine grained authorization or do they use some other out of the box applications such as IdentityServer4?

I have created user module, which contains information about user which has authentication with a token from Keycloak.

In that case i already found a pitfall where i would need to synchronize user with each authentication.